# Взаимодействие между объектами класса JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы

При написании проектной работы столкнулся с проблемой взаимодействия объектов одного класса. Допустим, у нас есть класс и два объекта этого класса:

```
class user {
    contructor(age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    method(){}
}

const user1 = new user(20);
const user2 - new user(30);
```

Как в методе method сравнить возраст user1 и user2?

Comment: передать параметром нужное значение и сравнить

Comment: На вход подаёшь второй объект и сравниваешь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать метод сравнения статичным методом класса, раз он не привязан к конкретном пользователю, а потом вызывать его с пользователями как аргументами.

```js
class User {
  constructor(age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
    
  static compare(user1, user2){
    return user1.age === user2.age;
  }
}

const user1 = new User(20);
const user2 = new User(30);
const user3 = new User(20);

console.log( User.compare(user1, user2) ); // false
console.log( User.compare(user1, user3) ); // true
```

Но можно, как предлагают в комментариях, сделать и нестатичный метод: тогда он будет у экземпляра и будет к нему привязан (например, можно сравнивать текущего пользователя с другим):

```js
class User {
  constructor(age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
    
  compareWith(anotherUser){
    return this.age === anotherUser.age;
  }
}

const user1 = new User(20);
const user2 = new User(30);
const user3 = new User(20);

console.log( user1.compareWith(user2) ); // false
console.log( user1.compareWith(user3) ); // true
```

Comment: Прекарсный ответ! Можете пожалуйста так же добавить пример с нестатичным методом типа `compareWith`, куда можно будет как параметр отправить другого пользователя, для полноты ответа? Буду признателен)

Comment: @EzioMercer добавил

Comment: Спасибо! Вы прекрасный ответчик)